# Finding the probability of arrangements on two groups of items in a specific order

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am given a `m` identical red balls and `n` identical blue balls. I want to find `(i)` the probability that the balls can be aranged such that exactly `k` red balls are grouped together i.e. `k` red balls comes consecutively in the arangement and `(ii)` the probability that exactly `k` red balls are grouped together only once.

For the first part, I found that the total number of arangements is ${n+m-(k+1)c + 1 \choose m-ck}\prod \limits_{i=1}^c (n+2-i)$ where $c = \lfloor \frac{m}{k}\rfloor$. The probability can be obtained by dividing the term with $m+n \choose n$. Is it correct ?

For the second one, I could not find a way to solve it.  Any help ?

Comment: What do "arranged" and  "$k$ balls are grouped together" mean?

Comment: @Henry. edited the question. by arangement i mean placing the balls like `bbrrb...` correspond to the arangement of `blueball blueball  redball redball ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first part you seem to be trying to count the arrangements that have $c$ blocks of exactly $k$ red balls with the remaining $m-ck$ red balls distributed arbitrarily. That is not how I interpret the question: I take it to be asking for arrangements that have at least one block of exactly $k$ red balls. These can be counted by an inclusion-exclusion argument. There are $n+1$ slots for red balls in the row of blue balls; number them from $1$ through $n+1$ and let $A_i$ be the set of arrangments that have a block of exactly $k$ red balls in slot $i$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
\left|\bigcup_{i\ge 1}A_i\right|&=\sum_{\varnothing\ne I\subseteq[n+1]}(-1)^{|I|+1}\left|\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i\right|\\
&=\sum_{\ell\ge 1}(-1)^{\ell+1}\binom{n+1}\ell\binom{m+n-(k+1)\ell}{m-k\ell}
\end{align*}$$

is the desired number of arrangements, where $\binom{n+1}\ell$ is the number of ways of choosing $\ell$ slots to be filled with blocks of exactly $k$ red balls, and $\binom{m+n-(k+1)\ell}{m-k\ell}$ is the number of ways to distribute the remaining $m-k\ell$ red balls amongst the remaining $n+1-\ell$ slots.

The number of arrangements with **no** block of exactly $k$ red balls is therefore

$$\begin{align*}
\binom{m+n}m&-\sum_{\ell\ge 1}(-1)^{\ell+1}\binom{n+1}\ell\binom{m+n-(k+1)\ell}{m-k\ell}\\
&=\binom{m+n}m+\sum_{\ell\ge 1}(-1)^\ell\binom{n+1}\ell\binom{m+n-(k+1)\ell}{m-k\ell}\\
&=\sum_{\ell\ge 0}(-1)^\ell\binom{n+1}\ell\binom{m+n-(k+1)\ell}{m-k\ell}\;.
\end{align*}$$

We can use this to count the arrangements with exactly one block of exactly $k$ red balls. If this $k$-block is in slot $1$, at the left end of the arrangment, it must be followed by a blue ball, and the remaining $m+n-k-1$ balls can be any arrangement of $m-k$ red and $n-1$ blue balls that has no block of exactly $k$ red balls; there are

$$\sum_{\ell\ge 0}(-1)^\ell\binom{n}\ell\binom{m-k+n-1-(k+1)\ell}{m-k-k\ell}$$

of these. In fact the count is the same no matter which slot holds the $k$-block: this is clear if it’s the last slot, and if it’s any other slot, removing the $k$-block and identifying the blue balls that were immediately adjacent to it also leaves an arrangement of $m-k$ red and $n-1$ blue balls that has no block of exactly $k$ red balls. Thus, there are

$$(n+1)\sum_{\ell\ge 0}(-1)^\ell\binom{n}\ell\binom{m-k+n-1-(k+1)\ell}{m-k-k\ell}$$

arrangements with exactly one block of exactly $k$ red balls.